# multiple form submitting using Ajax / laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have multiple comment forms in one page , when i submit the first form the data inserted in the database with no problems , but when i submit the others i got this error in the console **jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/addcomment 422 (Unprocessable Entity)**

this is my HTML code

```
<textarea class='form-control' name="comment" id ='comment'rows="1" placeholder=comment data-picid="{{$activitys->picture->id}}"></textarea>
```

this is my Ajax code:

```
var token = '{{  csrf_token() }}';
 var picture_id = 0;
 var urlcomment = ' {{route('comment.store')}} ';
 var comment;



$("#comment").submit(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  picture_id =event.target.dataset['picid'];
  comment = $("#comment").val();
  $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: urlcomment,
        data: {
          _token: token,
          comment: comment,
          picture_id: picture_id,
        },
success: function(data) {return false},
    });

  $('#comment').val('');
});
```

this is the function in the Controller :

```
// add data into database
 public function store(Request $request) {

     $this->validate($request, [
          'comment' => 'required|max:255',

      ]);


     $comment = new Comment();
     $comment->comment = $request->comment;
     $comment->user_id = Sentinel::getUser()->id;
     $comment->picture_id = $request->picture_id;
     $comment->save();
return response()->json($comment);
   }
```

*thank you alot please help .*

Comment: Could you please add all html forms code please ?

Comment: Bare in mind that id's must be unique in every page